# why text with different size have different alignment

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

i have this behavior:
[image]

Why the text have that space?
My goal is to left align the text with that one below.

Here what i have done:
CSS

```
.btn-basic {
  font-size: 5.8em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: medium none;
}

.btn-basic p {
   font-size: 0.3em;
   line-height: 1.0em;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="btn-basic">
   FREE WI-FI
   <p>Gratis. Senza limiti. Anche in streaming.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: You've styled them differently, so the margin is kinda expected.Try giving it 0 padding/margins.

Comment: there is no margin on the text, only a padding in the container.
However i have tried and nothing to do.

Comment: As @Paulie_D suggested, it could be a glyphs "issue". Have you tried to highlight the "F" to check if it's true ?

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, they have different size, but do you know a way to allineate them on the left? or i must rewrite the html?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the HTML...fonts have space around characters so they don't run into each other. Unfortunately, there is very little, if anything, you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Because character glyphs have space around them so they don't butt up against other character.

See:

```css
span {
  font-size: 144px;
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span>F</span>
<span>G</span>
<span>FG</span>
```

That 'space' may be different for each glyph (and font family). Combine that with the font-sizing you are using and you get the effect you are currently experiencing.

Unfortunately, there is very little you can do about it.

Comment: thank you to clarify the problem!
I am trying to figure out a workaround