# Vertically align text divs with responsive font-size within a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I have this div :

[image]

and I tried making the font-size of the text responsive using this code :

```
font-size:calc(xx + 1.5vw);
```

If I make the screen smaller the headers are not vertically aligned :

[image]

HTML :

```
<div id="topsection">
<div id="header1">HEADER 1</div>
<div id="header2">Header 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#header1 {
margin-left:220px;
font-size:calc(20px + 1.5vw);
color:#fff;
}

#header2 {
color: #fff;
margin-left:220px;
font-size:calc(9px + 1.5vw);
}

#topsection {
background-color:#222939;
width:100%;
height:75px;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:0;
color:white;
}
```

I tried changing the CSS for the headers like this :

```
#header1 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left:220px;
font-size:calc(20px + 1.5vw);
color:#fff;
}

#header2 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left:220px;
font-size:calc(9px + 1.3vw);
color: #fff;
}
```

but now it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Please follow [CSS Tricks - Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/). And please don't use `calc`.

Comment: You might need to set to line-height the same as height. I'll make an example within a few minutes.

Comment: @RichardLindhout I did it but it did not work for both headers

Comment: @Praveen Kumar It is not the same question. I have two text DIVS and it does not work with the line-height.

Comment: @RichardLindhout The reason it was closed was because they thought it was a duplicate. But in this case I have 2 divs with responsive text-size. :) The admin was fast though and the question is back.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619423/why-text-with-different-size-have-different-alignment/36619698#36619698

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a content div to center in the middle. See the example below. Have only tested this in Chrome.

```css
.toolbar{
background-color:#222939;
width:100%;
height:195px;
line-height:195px;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
color:white;


}
.toolbar .content{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.toolbar .title {


line-height:1;

font-size:calc(20px + 1.5vw);
color:#fff;
}

.toolbar .subtitle {


line-height:1;
font-size:calc(9px + 1.5vw);
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="toolbar">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">HEADER 1</div>
<div class="subtitle">Header 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Final code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .toolbar{
background-color:#222939;
width:100%;
height:195px;
line-height:195px;
z-index:1;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
color:white;
}
.toolbar .content{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.toolbar .title {
line-height:1;
font-size:calc(20px + 1.5vw);
color:#fff;
}

.toolbar .subtitle {
line-height:1;
font-size:calc(9px + 1.5vw);
color: #fff;
}
    </style>

    </head>
<body>
     <div class="toolbar">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">HEADER 1</div>
<div class="subtitle">Header 2</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested yours. It works fine on snippet but it does not work when I save the file and open in on chrome

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure you have the same html and css?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same.

Comment: It works. Is it possible to make it work without the <!DOCTYPE html> though? I cannot paste this code on the platform. The answer is correct though!

Comment: On which platform are you on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118553/discussion-between-richard-lindhout-and-apolo-radomer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a font glyph issue and is due to the fact that the black gylph *character* is not aligned directly along the left of the glyph *block*.

If you see the example below, you can set that there is actual space to the left side of the glyph *block* before the glyph *character*.

```css
h1,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 144px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 72px;
}
span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<H1><span>H</span></H1>
<H3><span>H</span></H3>
```

This is a font-design issue...and it's on purpose...so that letters don't automatically bunch up together.

The amount of space is proportional to the font-size and **each font** so there's no single value you can use to align them.

What works for one font won't work for the next.